# How to put Dataset query results into the body of an email

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I'm trying to make a program that emails the results of a query (in a dataset) to a user... My code is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Paid_Out_TbTableAdapter.Fill(Me.dataset.Paid_Out_Tb)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
            Net.NetworkCredential("Bob", "password")
            SmtpServer.Port = 25
            SmtpServer.Host = "server"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("email@email.com")
            mail.To.Add("Email@email.com")
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
            mail.Body = (Me.DataSet.Paid_Out_Tb.ToString)
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("mail send")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Everything works except sending the email body... How can i get the results to email as the body?

Comment: Do you need it to be easily human readable? You can get XML output from a DataSet, but people will go cross-eyed trying to read it.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error it just sends this as the body:
"Paid_Out_Tb"  Nothing else is displayed in the email...

Comment: @JamieSee, Yes it needs to show the results in the body so the user can quickly understand it.

Comment: If I change it to:
`mail.Body = (Me.Paid_Out_TbTableAdapter.Fill(Me.JLI_DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.Paid_Out_Tb))`  The body of the email is "4" which is the number of results... so I just need to find out how to display the results not the number of results...

Comment: @Shmewnix: the reason for your problem is that a `DataTable` doesn't have a human readable output for all the contents for its `ToString` method, just what you saw on the page. Similarly the `.Fill` method returns the number of rows in your datatable as you've said. All the data you need is in the datatable, you just need to extract it yourself (or find something else to do it) as ron tornambe has suggested in his answer. An HTML table is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq and VB's new inline xml literals capability to generate the html. Try this:

```
Dim payOuts = _
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><th>My First Column Header</th><th>My Second Column Header</th></tr>
            <%= From paidOut In Me.DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.Paid_Out_Tb.AsEnumerable _
                Select <tr>
                            <td><%= paidOut.MyFirstColum %></td>
                            <td><%= paidOut.MySecondColum %></td>
                       </tr> %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

mail.IsBodyHtml = True 
mail.Body = payouts.ToString
```

Be sure to include a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll in your project if it isn't already there. You'll also need `Imports System.Linq` on your class. See the Using [LINQ and XML Literals to transform a DataTable into a HTML table](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2009/04/Using-LINQ-and-XML-Literals-to-transform-a-DataTable-into-a-HTML-table.aspx) blog posting by Éric Moreau for a good explanation.

Comment: This is closer, the problem is it's still not picking up the info... `<%= From paidOut In Me.DataDeliveryServiceDataSet.Paid_Out_Tb.AsEnumerable _ Select <tr><td><%= paidOut.Store_Id %></td><td><%= paidOut.Paid_Out_Comment %></td></tr> %>` is not outputing anything... I get an email that says "My First Column Header My Second Column Header" nothing from the dataset..

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in your Paid_Out_Tb table? Try setting a breakpoint just before the new code and checking the contents.

Comment: Woops, Good call... I had the Fill below the HTML Code... What about auto format?  Is there a way to make things go to the next line?  Since the "Comment" section is so big it makes it look goofy if it's so big... Is it just standard HTML coding in that? or something automated based on the number of characters?

Comment: Yep, just like a web page, but to keep VB's literal XML happy you need to make sure that what you put in is XHTML compliant, i.e. `<br/>` not `<br>`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I guess what I mean is... It takes each record and wraps it... instead of taking down to the next line... so the 4 records are on the same line.after the headers.

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds odd. Can you pull out the contents of payOuts from debug, save it to a .html file and open it with a browser? If it's mangled in the browser it's something in the code. Put up the output and I'll look to see where it chokes. Otherwise, if it's only the e-mail that looks weird, then it's something about how the mail client behaves. One thing that would cause wrapping is if the opening `<tr>` or closing `</tr>` was missing from the select.

Comment: It works exported to a HTML file and loaded in a browser... almost like the email is not being formated for HTML...

Comment: mail.Body = payouts.ToString() returns the results in table form.
@JamieSee Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cycle through the rows of the dataset and extract the data you wish to email. You can format it using HTML by adding the following statement:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = True
```

Comment: I want all data found... Where would I add the Mail.isbodyhtml = true?